# Adding Subtitle to MediaPlayer android api level 9

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, android-video-player, subtitle

I want to integrate video playing feature with srt support from api level 9, I have been searching on google for this and ended up finding it has supported from  Jelly bean. Can anyone suggest how to add srt support for video in api level 9? Any library suggestion will do as well. Thanks